# From the following data of marks obtained by 2 students A and B, find who is more consistent.

Tags: statistics

From the following data of marks obtained by 2 students A and B, find who is more consistent.
   A (44, 80, 76, 48, 52, 72, 78, 56, 60, 54).

B (48, 75, 54, 60, 63, 69, 72, 51, 57, 66).

Comment: More consistent means a smaller variance (or standard deviation). Do you have a formula for such?

Comment: yea i think i get it. i have to find the mean, variance and standard deviation for each set of marks, then the data of marks with the smaller S.D which is closer to the mean belongs to the student who's more consistent, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: In R,`A= c(44, 80, 76, 48, 52, 72, 78, 56, 60, 54); B= c(48, 75, 54, 60, 63, 69, 72, 51, 57, 66); sd(A); sd(B)` returns `13.33333` and `9.082951`.